# Change getElementsByClassName()[i] field

Tags: javascript, replace, getelementsbyclassname

I'm doing kinda learning by doing `JavaScript` right know, but I have a problem, where I can not find the solution on stackoverflow. **I want to replace a String on a webpage, where I just have the `class`, but not the `ID`.**

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ep_price')[0]="FOO"
```

This should change the defined elemet to `FOO`, but it does not do that and I have no idea why not...

I have read that I should use `.value`, but this `var` is not even defined...

See Screenshot of my Chrome console below:

[image: Google Chrome JavaScript console![][1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.textContent` property if you intended to change the text.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ep_price')[0].textContent ="FOO"
```

Comment: @Robert glad to have helped :)

Comment: Bear in mind that IE doesn't implement `textContent`, instead using `innerText`.